# Finding the Number of $1$ in a Binary String

Tags: binary, bit-strings

Is there a general formula/ recurrence relation for finding the number $N$ of $1$ in an $n$ binary string representation of an integer $I$ ?

For the simplest case where $I\mod{2^n}=0$, it is easily seen that $N=1$

For $I=2^n+c\ \ \ \ $ where $\ \ \ \ c=2^{n-1}$, we have $N=2$

---

Now, when $2^n>c≥2^{n-1}$, we have $N=2+d$

if $c-2^{n-1}>2^{n-2}$, we have $d=1+e$ so $N=3+e$ and so on,

The process is so limited that it requires $I≥2^n$ so a modification is done to change $n$.
Is this process correct? Or is there any series/ generalization for the formula in counting the number of $1$ in a binary string of an integer?

Comment: $f(n)=\left(n\pmod 2\right)+f(\lfloor n/2\rfloor)$ with $f(0)=0$

Comment: Is https://oeis.org/A000120 your required sequence?

Comment: May I ask what does $f(n)$ represent?

Comment: $f(n)$ - the number of $1$'s in the binary representation of a non-negative integer $n$. The formula does this: chops off the "units" ($n\pmod 2$) and recursively applies itself to the rest "shifted right" by one place. ($n >> 1$ is the same as $\lfloor n/2\rfloor$).

Comment: What you have is basically the binary Hamming weight of $I$. Let’s call this $w(I)$. Then I guess the most you can get from this is: If $2^k|I$ then $w(I)=w(I/2^k)$. Else if $2\not|I$ then $w(I) = 1+w(I/2)$. Wich is more or less equivalent to calculating the binary representation and counting the 1s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brian Kernighan's  method is a well known algorithm for counting the set bits in a word. Here is some pseudocode:

```
count = 0;
while (I != 0) {
  I &= (I - 1);
  count++;
}
return count;
```

Comment: Some compilers will even recognize this exact code and compile it into a hardware "count the ones in this word" instruction on architectures that have one: https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/f36485f7ac2a8d72ad0e0f2134c17fd365272285/lib/Transforms/Scalar/LoopIdiomRecognize.cpp#L960

Comment: Why is Kernighan's cute code considered better than the more perspicacious $\mathtt{count = 0; while (I) \{count += I \,\&\, 1; I >>= 1;\}\,return\,count;}$

Comment: I guess I can answer my own comment: the loop in Kernighan's code is executed once per set bit, while the loop in mine is executed $\log_2(I)$ times. However, my code doesn't use addition, which would have been significantly slower than shifting in the Dark Ages of computing, so Kernighan and I could have had a debate on our hands. In the third decade of the 21st century, I don't think it matters.

Comment: @RobArthan: How dark are your dark ages if shifting was _faster_ than a plain addition? I'm not immediately aware of any machine that had wider shifters than the word length its ALU could add in a single clock cycle. Overall, both loop bodies have three ALU instructions in the loop body, plus most likely a move instruction to copy `I` -- but in several instruction sets I know of, yours would need longer instruction _encodings_, and in the dark ages instruction fetches mattered for performance ...

Comment: Very dark and very obscure, specifically array processors like the [ICL DAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICL_Distributed_Array_Processor) and other much older things where each carry step in an addition cost a cycle.

Comment: https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/popcnt